# Angularjs - Invoke Function from module.config

Tags: angularjs, config, angularjs-scope, restangular

I have a code of

```
var viewerAngular = angular.module('ngAppDemo', ['restangular','btford.socket-io'])
.config(function(RestangularProvider) {
$.get('../config/config.xml',
        function(data) {

            $(data).find('contentserver').each(function() {
                serverDetails.contentserver = assignServerDetails($(this));
                var restprovider = RestangularProvider;
                restprovider.setBaseUrl("http://"+serverDetails.contentserver.ip+":"+serverDetails.contentserver.port+"\:"+serverDetails.contentserver.port);
                //$scope.init();
            });

    });
```

I need to invoke function `init()`, after reading the config(`../config/config.xml`) file. 
I got an error of `ReferenceError: $scope is not defined`.

How can I add `$scope` in `module.config`? Or How can I call function from config?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to add something to every scope in config, you can use `$rootScope`, but it's better practice to create a service for that data.

Answer (score 0):

You can not ask for instance during configuration phase - you can ask only for providers.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

// configure stuff
app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
  // you can inject any provider here
});

// run blocks
app.run(function($rootScope) {
  // you can inject any instance here
});
```

See http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module for more info.

Answer (score 0):

```
var viewerAngular = angular.module('ngAppDemo', ['restangular','btford.socket-io'])
.config(function(RestangularProvider) {
$.get('../config/config.xml',
    function(data) {

        $(data).find('contentserver').each(function() {
            serverDetails.contentserver = assignServerDetails($(this));
            var restprovider = RestangularProvider;
            restprovider.setBaseUrl("http://"+serverDetails.contentserver.ip+":"+serverDetails.contentserver.port+"\:"+serverDetails.contentserver.port);
            var Scope=angular.element(document.querySelector('[ng-controller="controllerName"]')).scope();
            Scope.init();
        });

});
```

Comment: don't do that. Just cause you can do something, doesn't mean it is a good thing to do it. I'd suggest you reorganize your app.

Comment: @baba I didn't get you. What shall I do?

Comment: In your config, don't access the scope, nor call any function on it. Whatever you are doing, there are other ways to do that.

Comment: "I need to invoke function init(), after reading the config(../config/config.xml) file". Generally, config is done before rendering controllers, so you don't have to call init from the config, but you can call it immediately from your controller.

Comment: My controller invoked before the config file. I have to use `serverDetails.contentserver` inside controller. Then how can I do?

Comment: Just don't invoke the controller before the config file. It is that simple.

Comment: @baba How can I do that? Always my controller get invoke before the cofig.